# Non-portable pointer conversion

Tags: c, file, loops

I am writing a program that takes strings from two files and combines them to make a third file with the combined string.

```
#define BUF 255

int main( void)
{
    FILE *usernames; FILE *passwords; FILE *final_file;
    char *user_str, *pass_str;
    int ct, ck;

    usernames = fopen( ".\\info_files\\usernames.txt", "r" );
    passwords = fopen( ".\\info_files\\passwords.txt", "r" );
    final_file = fopen( ".\\info_files\\usernamesPasswords.txt", "w" );

    if ( (usernames == NULL) || (passwords == NULL) || (final_file == NULL) 
    )
    {

        printf( "failed to open one of the files" );

    }

    while ( (fgets( user_str, BUF, usernames) != EOF ) && ( fgets( pass_str, BUF, passwords) != EOF)) 
    {       
        fprintf( final_file, "%-25s %s\n", user_str, pass_str );        
    }   



    fclose( usernames );
    fclose( passwords );
    fclose( final_file );

    return 0;
}
```

This is what's giving me trouble. I have no idea what is causing this to crash. 
This is edited from what was first posted.

Comment: `while(fgets(user_str, BUF, usernames) && fgets(pass_str, BUF, passwords)){ fprintf( final_file, "%-25s %s\n", user_str, pass_str ); }`

Comment: Possibly you want to remove newlines from `user_str`

Comment: BLUEPIXY and M.M. I am still getting non portable pointer conversion warning.

Comment: `fgets()` returns a pointer, not an `int`.

Comment: David Bowling, a pointer to what and thats not really my question I added some code so you guys could look at the other stuff.

Comment: `!= EOF` --> `!= NULL`, `char *user_str, *pass_str;` --> `char user_str[BUF], pass_str[BUF];`

Comment: Don't modify question code based on comments; this only makes existing comments and answers confusing to others who come across this later; if you need to, add an Edit. You  had `int ct, ck;` receiving the return value from `fgets()` This is wrong, because `fgets()` returns a pointer to `char`. Now you are comparing the return value with `EOF`, also wrong. [Read the docs](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.7.2).

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I'm wanting it to check for the end of the file at that point not NULL

Comment: Read  **Return value** of reference of [fgets](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets)

Comment: Ahh thank you @BLUEPIXY I know I've been on here a lot but I'm taking a smummer class and my teacher isn't really doing anything besides grading.

Comment: `user_str` is not assigned nor initialized --> `fgets( user_str, BUF, usernames)` --> UB.

Comment: How much *Storage* do you have at the location pointed to by `user_str` and `pass_str`?? How about `char user_str[BUF] = ""; pass_str[BUF] = "";`??

Answer (score 1):

@BLUEPIXY has given you the correct code - Here's the explanation of where you went wrong in your code:-

> char *fgets(char *str, int n, FILE *stream)
>
> reads a line from the specified stream and stores it into the string pointed to by str. It stops when either (n-1) characters are read, the newline character is read, or the end-of-file is reached, whichever comes first.
>
> ### Retun value of fgets
>
> On success: the function returns the same str parameter
>
> If the End-of-File is encountered and no characters have been read,
>   the contents of str remain unchanged and a null pointer is returned
>
> If an error occurs, a null pointer is returned.

Source:- [C Tutorial Point](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fgets.htm)

Comment: I see a description of `fgets()`, but I don't see the promised explanation of how OP went wrong....